# Plotting a numpy array as a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've the following code that I'm using to plot a numpy array as a histogram. All I end up getting is a box.

```
from sys import argv as a
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = list(map(int, (a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5])))
s = np.array([int((x - min(r))/(max(r) - min(r)) * 10) for x in r])
plt.hist(s, normed=True, bins=5)
plt.show()
```

The program is run with the following inputs
22 43 11 34 26

How can I get a histogram with the y axis representing the heights of list elements.

Comment: The 'normed' kwarg was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.1 and will be removed in 3.1. Use 'density' instead.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar):

```
plt.bar(np.arange(len(s)),s)
plt.show()
```

Which turns into the below. Is that your expected output?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get a histogram with the y axis representing the values of list elements.

Per definition a histogram gives the number of elements, which fall into certain bins, or the probability to find the element in a certain bin. 
`plt.hist` is plotting function that draws a bar chart from such a histogram.

So what happens when you call `plt.hist(s, normed=True, bins=5)` is that the normalized input array `s = [ 3, 10,  0,  7,  4]` is divided into 5 bins between 0 and 10. There is exactly one number from `s` falling into each bin, so all bars in the hisogram plot have the same height.

[image]

Since in this case you don't actually want to have a histogram at all, but only a bar chart of the values, you should use [`plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) with the array `s` as height argument and some index as position.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ["some file", "22", "43", "11","34", "26"]

r = list(map(int, (a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5])))
s = np.array([int((x - min(r))/(max(r) - min(r)) * 10) for x in r])

plt.bar(np.arange(len(s)), s)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using matplotlib and numpy. Just plain python.

Comment: Is this a question? If so, I would say, yes theoretically it is possible, but it will cost you 4 days to write the code to do it. The good thing about libraries such as matplotlib and numpy is that you don't need to care about some of the basics and thus the code is very short. There are of course also other libraries for statistics and plotting around, which you may use instead.

Comment: Thanks!! Had the same question, this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_values = [1, 2, 0.25, 15]
x = np.arange(len(your_values))

plt.bar(
    x, 
    your_values
)
```

[Here is the example of the resulting bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Cuc.png)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.